# How to Send SMS through PHP

Tags: php, android, email, sms, smpp

- create and import contacts and groups. send a single SMS, or send
- bulk SMS to a group or multiple groups. connect to any SMS gateway
- with minimal configuration. customize your SMS or email. add a link to your SMS 
  and email.

The message is composed using a web application that is stored and executed on a HTTP server and then sent through the internet ("the cloud") as an email message.
The email is received by a Short Message Service Gateway (SMS Gateway), which converts the message from an email message to a SMS message.
The SMS message is then handed to a Short Message Service Center (SMSC), which is a server that routes data to specific mobile devices.
The message is finally transmitted over the wireless network to the recipient.
Most wireless networks have a SMS gateway through which email messages can be sent as text messages to a mobile device. This is nice, because, from a developer's standpoint, it is generally free—however, it is of course not a free service for the end user. Fees still apply to the recipient of the message and messages sent via email will be billed as a non-network text message

Answer (score 0):

we can use php mail() function to send sms but you have to purchase the SMPP frome network provider

Answer (score 0):

you can use gateway like way2sms gateway for php send sms through php

Comment: any way the sms can be send know

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive when answering a question. Adding an example would be even better.

Comment: But  way2sms gateway is having limited messages per year. I already used that gateway

Answer (score 0):

easy use a sms getaway, we use https://developers.messagebird.com/docs/sms-messaging for a phone validation